# How to create a dictionary from a file with multiple lines

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to create a dictionary from multiple lines in a file, for i.e.

```
grocery store
apples
banana
bread

shopping mall
movies
clothing stores
shoe stores
```

What I'm trying to do is make the first row of each section (i.e. grocery store and shopping mall) the keys and everything underneath (apple, banana, bread & movies, clothing stores, shoe stores respectively) the values. I've been fiddling around with the readline approach + while loop, but I haven't been able to figure it out. If anyone knows, please help. Thanks.

Comment: It's actually easier to use a `for` loop instead of `while`. `for` will exit on it's own when you reach the end of the file

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to store in a variable the boolean value for whether you're at the start of a section. I don't want to give away the exciting (?) ending, but you could start with `is_first=True`.

OK, I guess I do want to give away the ending after all. Here's what I had in mind, more or less:

```
with open(fname) as f:
    content = f.readlines()

is_first = True
d = {}

for line in content:
    if line == '\n':
        is_first = True
    elif is_first:
        key = line
        is_first = False
    else:
        if key not in d:
            d.put(key, '')
        d.put(key, d.get(key) + line)
        is_first = False
```

I find it easier to plan the code that way. Of course you could also solve this without an `is_first` variable, especially if you've already gone through the exercise of doing it with an `is_first` variable. I think the following is correct, but I wasn't incredibly careful:

```
with open(fname) as f:
    content = f.readlines()

d = {}

while content:
    key, content = content[0], content[1:]
    if key != '\n':
        value, content = content[0], content[1:]
        while value != '\n':
            if key not in d:
                d.put(key, '')
            d.put(key, d.get(key) + value)
            value, content = content[0], content[1:]
```

Comment: okay, so would I do something like .. 
line = f.readline()
line_first = True (or make a boolean statement regarding the first line of each section?)

Comment: Yes, then think it over: How do you know when you're no longer looking for the first line of a section? How do you know when a section has ended and you've begun to look for the first line of the next section? Keep `line_first` updated accordingly.

Comment: okay, so I'm super confused, how do I read the file and then grab the first word of each section?

Comment: What do you do differently when you look at the input line and see that it's blank?

Comment: I should skip over it. I mean, I get that I can say first_line = file.readline() .. which would give me the first line of the first section. But, idk, I'm just at a loss here.

Comment: Well, I sometimes hope to guide the questioner to the answer. It doesn't always work out for me. I've explained further.

Comment: Oh, wow. Thank-you so much, I just need to get a better hang of these kinds of problems! But, this explained a lot. Thanks a lot !

Comment: No need for the `f.close()` if you're using the `with`.

Comment: `f.readlines()` reads the entire file into memory at once. It can be faster to do it that way but beware of using it with very large input files.

Answer (score 1):

@minopret has already given a pedagogically useful answer, and one that's important for beginners to understand.  In a sense, even some more seemingly-sophisticated approaches are often doing that under the hood -- using a kind of state machine, I mean -- so it's important to know.

But for the heck of it, I'll describe a higher-level approach.  There's a handy function `itertools.groupby` which groups sequences into contiguous groups.  In this case, we can define a group by a bunch of lines which aren't all empty -- `bool(line)` is `False` if the line is empty and `True` otherwise, and then build a `dict` from them.

```
from itertools import groupby

with open("shopdict.txt") as fin:
    stripped = map(str.strip, fin)
    grouped = (list(g) for k,g in groupby(stripped, bool) if k)
    d = {g[0]: g[1:] for g in grouped}
```

Comment: Cool, I get to learn too. This illustrates why the Python documentation says of the Library Reference, "keep this under your pillow", doesn't it? Knowing the library, or even when to peruse the library, can save mountains of effort. (Other things that help: make some smart friends, learn Haskell, earn a PhD in computer science, etc.!)

Comment: Python3 has a beautiful way to write the last line! `d = {k: g for k, *g in grouped}`

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import groupby
with open("shopdict.txt") as fin:
    stripped = map(str.strip, fin)
    d = {k: g for b, (k, *g) in  groupby(stripped, bool) if b}
```

And here's a way just using `for` loops

```
d={}
with open("shopdict.txt") as fin:
    for key in fin:
        key = key.strip()
        d[key] = []
        for item in fin:
            if item.isspace():
                break
            d[key].append(item.strip())
```